# Error when suspending after locking screen

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, suspend, power-management

I have a shortcut key set to bring up the login screen by running:

```
dm-tool switch-to-greeter
```

Recently I decided that it would be more useful to me to only explicitly lock my screen this way, so in the Xfce Power Manager > Security tab I unchecked "Lock screen when system is going for sleep".

However, since this time I have been getting errors.  Occasionally when I shut the lid the computer fails to sleep, and when I open the lid and dismiss the lock screen it is asking for me to enter a password because it apparently lacks permission to go to sleep (?!!!).  But most of the time it works, yet when I wake up the machine and pass the lock screen a notification pops up:

```
Power Manager
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationInProgress: 
There's already a shutdown or sleep operation in progress
```

This is annoying because it doesn't go away and I actually have to take the trouble to move the mouse up to click it.  Why are these errors occurring and how can I get rid of them?